# how to invoke a method from Spring EL

Tags: spring-el

scenario

```
Car car= new Car()
car.setRegNumber("12345");

//check if the last 3 digit is matching
String expresionString="( Math.abs(regNumber) % 1000  == 345 )"
```

But the above expression fails with error "property or field 'Math' cant be found on object Car'. Ss there another way instead of using string conversion/substring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `matches` operator:

```
String expresionString="( regNumber matches '.*345$' )"
```

It matches if the last 3 disgits are 345

or simply

```
String expresionString="( regNumber.endsWith('345') )";
```

if you want to use static methods like in your example, you have to put the classname into `T(..)`

```
String expresionString="T(Math).abs(T(Integer).valueOf(regNumber)) % 1000  == 345";
```